# función split para omitir encabezados

Tags: javascript

Obtengo un domicilio de un textbox con JQUERY, pero es una cadena larga la cual es "Calle y No:XXXXXXXXXColonia:XXXXXXXXXXMunicipio:XXXXXXXXXXEstado:XXXXXXXXXXCP:XXXXXX", de la cual quiero omitir "Calle y No:","Colonia:", "Municipio:", "Estado:" y "CP:", estoy aplicando la funcion split

```js
        var element = $("#txtDomicilio").val();
        var fecha = element.split('Calle y No:');
        var fecha1 = element.split('Colonia:');
        var fecha2 = element.split('Municipio:');
        var fecha3 = element.split('Estado:');
        var fecha4 = element.split('CP:');
        alert('Fecha formateada: ' + fecha);
        alert('Fecha formateada: ' + fecha1);
        alert('Fecha formateada: ' + fecha2);
        alert('Fecha formateada: ' + fecha3);
        alert('Fecha formateada: ' + fecha4);
```

pero de esa forma solo me omite para `var fecha = element.split('Calle y No:');` Calle y No:, pero no Colonia:, Municipio: ..., ¿Como puedo hacer para que me omita lo que tengo en las funciones split? todo de una sola vez y no por separado como lo tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿hay algun caracter separador? puede poner un ejemplo con datos falsos en formato de texto ?

Comment: solamente los dos puntos después de los encabezados o también puede ser todo el texto "Calle y No:", "Colonia:"...

Comment: ¿Siempre va a tener los mismos campos?¿Y en el mismo orden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sabes los nombres de los diferentes parámetros que se van a pasar, puedes añadir un carácter especial delante de cada uno de ellos, después romper la cadena por ese carácter que acabas de crear (usando `split`), y lo que te quedará es un array con el parámetro y su valor separado por el `:` original. Sólo te quedaría atravesar ese nuevo array y separar los valores uno a uno (de nuevo usando `split`).

Algo como esto (uso un objeto para guardarlo, pero podrías hacer cualquier otra operación):

```js
var element = "Calle y No:11111111Colonia:22222222Municipio:33333333Estado:44444444CP:55555555";
var datos = ["Calle y No", "Colonia", "Municipio", "Estado", "CP"];
var resultado = {};

datos.forEach(function(el, idx) {
  element = element.replace(el+":", "|"+el+":");
});

element.split("|").forEach(function(el) {
  if (el != "") {
    var pareja = el.split(":");
    resultado[pareja[0]] = pareja[1];
  }
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: ok, si necesito solo los valores por ejemplo el "11111111","22222222","33333333" para posterior concatenarlos, le tendria que hacer un split a la varariable pareja que esta dentro del if (el != "") ?

Comment: Si sólo necesitas los valores, podrías guardarlos de otra manera. Yo Los he guardado en un objeto/array asociativo para que se puedan acceder fácilmente después, pero igual puedes ponerlos en un array simple o en una cadena, solo tendrías que preocuparte por Los valores de pareja[1]

Answer (score 0):

asumiendo que los campos siempre están presentes y van en ese orden, puedes aplicar .split() iterativamente en sentido inverso, empezando por el último. Y colocando los valores obtenidos en un array de resultados, empujando con .unshift() al inicio del mismo.

Algo así como...

```
var separadores = ['Calle y No:','Colonia:','Municipio:','Estado:','CP:'];
var a = [element];
var resultados = [];
for (var i=separadores.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
  a = a[0].split(separadores[i]);
  resultados.unshift(a[1]);
}
```